# Does Process Explorer support API or call from Console Command?

Tags: winapi, dll, com, find, process-explorer

Suppose I've installed multiple version of a software, some of the DLLs are register as COM. 
For example:

```
.../version1/Application.exe
             normal.dll
             comObject.dll -- register as COM to use
.../version2/Application.exe
             normal.dll
             comObject.dll -- register as COM to use
```

**How can know which comObject.dll is registered?**(which path? under folder "version1" or "version2"?)
**Answer:** One way of doing this is to use "Process Explorer", go to *"Find | Find Handle or DLL...*", input "comObject.dll" and click "Search" button.
**Then the path is shown in the list**.

**NOW COMES TO MY QUESTION:** If a software package is huge with hundreds of COM based DLLs installed, I don't want to manually open "Peocess Explorer" and search each DLL/OCX/EXE, more than that, in the search result, it is impossible for me to copy the list contents out!!

All I want is a tool to run like following command and I can run in a bat file.

```
ProcessExplorer.exe -Find "comObject1.dll" -append "C:\temp\output.txt"
ProcessExplorer.exe -Find "comObject2.dll" -append "C:\temp\output.txt"
ProcessExplorer.exe -Find "comObject3.dll" -append "C:\temp\output.txt"
```

output.txt can be looks like this:

---

```
Process          PID   Type  Handle or DLL
comObject1.dll    1    DLL   C:\ApplicationExample\Version1\comObject1.dll
comObject2.dll    1    DLL   C:\ApplicationExample\Version1\comObject2.dll
comObject3.dll    1    DLL   C:\ApplicationExample\Version2\comObject3.dll
```

In the example above, comObject1.dll and comObject2.dll are from Version1 folder,
while comObject3.dll is from Version2 folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command-line equivalents of the great Process Explorer are [ListDlls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656) and [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655). That's probably what you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks eran!

Comment: @eran is there any such tool to get information about command-line of process, I want the command line tool to extract command the process is running.

Comment: The only downside I'm finding is that handle.exe isn't listing svchost handles, whereas Process Explorer does. I'm aware this answer is 9 years old.